# How to use $header in routes

Tags: apache-camel

I'm creating a route using the Java DSL in Camel.

I'd like to perform a text substitution without creating a new processor or bean.

I have this:

```
.setHeader(MY_THING,
    constant(my_template.replace("{id1}", simple("${header.subs_val}").getText())))
```

If I don't add 'constant' I get type mismatch errors. If I don't put getText() on the simple() part, I get text mismatch answers. When I run my route, it replaces `{id}` with the literal `${header.subs_val}` instead of fetching my value from the header. Yet if I take the quotes off, I get compile errors; Java doesn't know the `${...}` syntax of course.

Deployment takes a few minutes, so experiments are expensive.

So, how can I just do a simple substitution. Nothing I am finding on the web actually seems to work.

EDIT - what is the template?  Specifically, a string (it's a URL)

```
http://this/that/{id1}/another/thing
```

I've inherited some code, so I am unable to simply `to(...)` the URL and apply the special `.tof()` (??) formatting.

Comment: What is my_template in your example?

Comment: And how my_template is related to the exchange? If you like provide more details, I am trying to reproduce the case. I understand that you want to replace a parameter called id in the template with the content of header.subs_val, but I cannot figure out what the template is.

Comment: @ltsallas Edits made

Comment: so my_template is not in a header or property inside the exchange? It is hardcoded in the route?

Comment: @ltsallas That is correct. The result is placed into the header, and the substitution value comes from the exchange.

Comment: @ltsallas Well, it's injected, not hardcoded, but the template does not come from the exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting case!

If you place my_template in a header you could use a nested simple expression(Camel 2.9 onwards) like in the example below. I am also setting a value to subs_val for the example, but I suppose your header has already a value in the route.

```
  .setHeader("my_template", constant("http://this/that/{id1}/another/thing"))
  .setHeader("subs_val",constant("22"))
  .setHeader("MY_THING",simple("${in.header.my_template.replaceAll(\"\\{id1.?\",${in.header.subs_val.toString()})}"))
```

After this step header MY_THING has the value http://this/that/22/another/thing.

1)In this example I could  skip to_String() but I do not know what's the type of your header "subs_val" .

2) I tried first with  replaceAll(\"\{id1\"}\") but it didn't work with } Probably this is a bug...Will look at it again. That's why in my regex I used .?

3) When you debug your application inside a processor, where the exchange is available you can use SimpleBuilder to evaluate a simple expression easily in your IDE, without having to restart your app

```
 SimpleBuilder.simple("${in.header.url.replaceAll(\"\\{id1.?\",${in.header.subs_val.toString()})}").evaluate(exchange, String.class);
```

Hope it helped :)

Comment: Thank you. While there's no reason for the template to be in the header, it won't hurt anything to be there, either. Your substitution above is much cleaner than using an implementation of Processor, which is what I ended up doing.

Comment: I just read your latest comment that the template is injected. Simple language offers a bunch of different options to read values(external properties,beans,etc) See the variables in https://camel.apache.org/simple.html. Maybe one of this options is more clean. If you like add parts of your route (particularly this  template injection part) so we can  figure out whether one of the other available simple expression values can help to avoid this setting in the header of the exchange

Comment: I can see that would be even cleaner.

Comment: We ended up implementing pretty much exactly what you have above.

Comment: Nice...about the regex i mentioned in my point (2),i opened a jira ticket and it is already fixed for camel 2.18.so it could become more strict,see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-9898